# Vuejs Computed Setter with an object two way data binding

Tags: vue.js, wysiwyg, quill

Following the basic example how two-ways databinding works:

```
<template>
<input v-model="fullname"/>
<input v-model="first"/>
<input v-model="last"/>
</template>
<script>
    var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        first: '',
        last: ''
      },
      computed: {
        fullname: {
          // getter function
          get: function() {
            return this.first + " " + this.last
          },
          // setter function
          set: function(value) {
            var name = value.split(' ')
            this.first = name[0]
            this.last = name[1]
          }
        }
      }
    })
</script>
```

As shown here: https://youtu.be/PuxdMnk-u5k?t=17m43s (17:43) - you can easily modify data of first and last name within fullname input.

Now my case is just a little different. I've got an object as below:

```
myObject: [
   {active: true, itemId: "55", text: 'some text', textOutput: ''}
   {active: true, itemId: "56", text: 'some text', textOutput: ''}
   {active: true, itemId: "58", text: 'some text', textOutput: ''}
   {active: true, itemId: "65", text: 'some text', textOutput: ''}
   {active: true, itemId: "105", text: 'some text', textOutput: ''}
]
```

next I modify this a little bit via computed - here just add to each item `<li>` tags:

```
modifyArrayItem () {
  var output=''
    for (var i=0; i<this.myObject.length; i++) {
      if (this.myObject[i].active) {
        this.myObject[i].textOutput= '<li>' + this.myObject[i].text + '</li>'
        output = output + this.myObject[i].textOutput
      }
      else {
        this.myObject[i].textInput = ''
      }          
    }
    return output
  },
```

and then outputing only active items via v-html

```
<div  v-html="modifyArrayItem"></div>
```

Easy so far. Now I want to be able to edit output in my html via, let's say quill-editor like this:

```
<quill-editor v-model="modifyArrayItem" :options="options"></quill-editor>
```

Can it be done?

What should I do to be able to edit `myObject[n-element].text` and `myObject[n-element].textOutput` basing on `itemId` number within my quill editor field? (please note that `[n-element] != itemId`).

How to prevent edited data loss on dynamically changing `myObject.active` of each element to true/false  while editing? How about saving edited text into seperated variable?

edit: some idea - add some kind of invisible tag with itemId value to quill-editor for each `<li>`?

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle of something? It looks like `modifyArrayItem()` returns a string. Then how do you want to access it's n-th element? What is `proTemplate`? Now I can only tell you to use either `sync` modifier or events. Find how to use them in docs.

Comment: @oniondomes sorry I've corrected it into `myObject` now. This is the main problem how to access n-th element. I think that it could be done by referring to `itemId` which is intended to be unique. I want to do it somehow similar to the first example. Sync or events could be valuable advice, I'll look for them

Comment: The easiest solution would be to pass an actual array and transform it to a string inside editor component. Thus, you can key Ids and send them back to the parent.

Comment: @oniondomes do you mean many editors - each one on single component template? one on every single `<li>`? or sth like that? I consider this as a last-stand solution, because my user will not be able to move cursor between editors /li's

Comment: maybe add some kind of invisible tag with itemId value to quill-editor?

Comment: Once again try to reproduce your code jsfiddle/code/code snippet here. We're spending time on understanding the question, not finding a solution. Many editors is not what I meant. It is unclear what `quill-editor` capable of because of no context.

Comment: @oniondomes starting point here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bLJoyo?editors=1011

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can parse the HTML into lines, and assign the lines to their corresponding entry in `myObject`.

However, be aware that updating the contents of the editor every time you type something causes the cursor to move to the beginning of the editor.

It turns out quill has a way of getting and setting selection position. It gets a little hairy, because each edit calls set twice, so you have to check whether anything is actually changing. But this works:

```
modifyArrayItem: {
  get() {
    return this.myObject.map(o => "<li>" + o.text + "</li>").join("");
  },
  set(newValue) {
    const oldLines = this.myObject.map((o) => o.text);
    const lines = newValue.split("</p>")
      .map((p) => p.replace('<p>', ''));
    const same = oldLines.join('') === lines.join('');

    if (!same) {
      const pos = this.$refs.quill.quill.getSelection();
      for (let i=0; i < this.myObject.length; ++i) {
        this.myObject[i].text = lines[i];
      }
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.$refs.quill.quill.setSelection(pos);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rJbYeg?editors=1011)

Comment: let me see... this cursor moving to the beginning will probably eliminate this solution. I need it works as normal typing. The other idea was to put 5 quill editors one after another in the same page for each `<li>`, but there will be cursor problem moving between them

Comment: Thank you, you are my StackOverflow hero :D